Как получить путь в PathVariable?
Я делаю REST API на spring boot web.
И мне нужно скачать файл по какому то пути, например foo/baar/file.txt
У меня такой маппинг - files/download/{file:.*} (полный путь api/v1/files/download/{file:.+})
если я перейду по api/v1/files/download/foo.txt то начнется выполнение моего кода на поиск и отправку файла,
но если я перейду по api/v1/files/download/baar/file.txt то тогда мой код не будет выполняться, вернет 404 и все, как это исправить?
